# Android permissions preventing visibility on Google Play

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I've now release my app 4 times with different configurations in the manifest to try and get the app available for download on Tablets that do not have phone connectivity.

I'm pretty sure I have the Manifest permissions correct after reading many many articles on similar issues.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"  android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  android:required="false" />
```

Can anyone see what might be the issue that is preventing this app from being available for download for some tablets? For example, we have a 7" Samsung TAB2 without telephony (GT-P3110), yet the app is not shown when searching GP.

The supported devices listing in the developer console when filtered by "samsung galaxy tab2" gives me these:

```
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 10.1 – espresso10can
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 10.1 – espresso10vzw
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 10.1 – espresso10att
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 7.0– espressowifi
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 10.1 – espresso10tmo
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 10.1– espresso10rf
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 7.0– espressorf
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 7.0 – espressovzw
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 10.1– espresso10wifi
SamsungGalaxy Tab2 10.1 – espresso10spr
```

Confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone see what might be the issue that is preventing this app from being available for download for some tablets?

Among perhaps other things, your last four `<uses-feature>` elements are wrong. The values for `android:name` need to be ones [documented for `<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference). Instead, you are using permission names, which will not work. You may particularly wish to examine [the mapping of permissions to implied hardware features](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions), so that you can say that the *features* are not required.

Comment: thanks, only two in the last 4 lines appear to be not listed:
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS & android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
Have uploaded without those 2, waiting for GP to relist so I check any difference...

Comment: @Mark: "only two in the last 4 lines appear to be not listed" -- perhaps, but **all four** of your elements were wrong. Any `<uses-feature>` element that has `permission` somewhere in the `android:name` attribute is wrong, because **none of the available features have `permission` in their name**. [The mapping of permissions to implied hardware features](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) shows you the *feature* names that you should use in `<uses-feature>` that *correspond* to certain permissions that you may be requesting.

Comment: I understand you now, thanks for detailing, changed to:
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />